# Compare two columns

Tags: excel, excel-formula

probably simple question:

Have two columns:

```
A containing datetimes formatted as: m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM
B containing datetimes (but as Text!)
```

From the view perspective all looks the same. Now i would like to put formula to column C and see if there is/not diffrence between two columns A and B. How to do that?

I tried so far: `=IF(A1=B1,”True”,”False”)` but doesn't work at all.

Comment: Have you tried `=IF(A1=DateValue(B1),"True","False")`?

Comment: @Ralph not working i see @VALUE!

Comment: Please post a screenshot of the data in columns A & B aside with some sample data (inserted into the above post). Otherwise, we cannot help you convert the text string to a true date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
=A1=VALUE(B1)
```

You don't need the IF statement as this will return true or false depending on the result.

This will only work if the formatting in column A matches your locale date format. For example it doesn't work for me because UK formatting is `day/month/year` not `month/day/year`, but having column A as `d/m/yyyy ...` works for me. If your formatting is different then you will need to extract the date using string manipulation and something like `DATEVALUE` + `TIMEVALUE`

Comment: Thats work, have additional question : If i would like to only convert what i see between those two column (Text not values behind how could i do this?)

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, if you wanted to compare the actual date string you can use `TEXT` like Dwendl suggested, but this has no difference over comparing the values like I suggested.

Comment: Now i am talking about other two columns, first is for datetime formatted as hours:minutes:seconds (hours could exceed normal clock and contains also days*24). second column is just text. So for example:A: 666:00:00 (backing value: 1/27/1900  6:00:00 PM) B: 666:00:00 now i want to compare if there are matching (in this case yes).

Answer (score 0):

If you have any leading or trailing spaces in text dates in column B that may cause the issues.

You may try something like this

```
=A1=TRIM(B1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Would
    `=IF(TEXT(A1,"m/d/yyyy hh:mm:ss AM/PM")=B1,"True","False")`
work for you? Assuming you want the text True or False.

Comment: got two same values and giving me false for example: 11/1/2016  12:00:00 AM P.S i dont know why in column A where dates are as values there is always two spaces between date part and time part.

Comment: That date/time gives me True. I'm curious why we get different results.